# Application unexpectedly closes while using multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, blockingcollection

I was trying out a very simple Producer Consumer approach using `BlockingCollection` as per the article described here: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview) to understand multithreading.

My producer is a single task which reads from an XML file (has around 4000 nodes) and pushes `XElement` nodes to a blocking collection.

My consumer will have multiple threads reading from the blocking collection and uploading files to a site based on the `XElement`.

The problem here is that the program unexpectedly closes every time I try to run it. It hits the producer `Task.Run` but stops after that. I'm not able to understand the reason why. Am I doing something wrong? It doesn't even hit the `catch` block.

Code is below:

```
            BlockingCollection<XElement> collection = new BlockingCollection<XElement>(100);                
            string metadataFilePath = exportLocation + listTitle + "\\Metadata\\" + exportJobId + ".xml";
            //create the producer
            Task.Run(() =>
            {                    
                //Process only the files that have not been uploaded                                   
                XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(metadataFilePath);
                var query = from c in xmlFile.Elements("Items").Elements("Item")
                            where c.Attribute("IsUploaded").Value == "No"
                            select c;
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    collection.Add(item);
                }
                collection.CompleteAdding();
            });

            //process consumer
            Parallel.ForEach(collection, (new System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }), (metadata) => {
                ProcessItems();
            });
```

Comment: cna you put a breakpoint inside of the task.run?

Comment: I did. It executes some statements then just closes suddenly.

Comment: Could it be because you are adding to a collection in a separate thread, and then potentially accessing it in the `Parallel.ForEach()`? Maybe you need to put a `lock` around the `collection.Add()` statement

Comment: Not sure. The docs mention that this is already handled by the blocking collection. I've tried a very similar variant of the example they mention as will but with the same result.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice you were using `BlockingCollection`

Comment: Are you by any chance blowing the stack? There are some odd corner cases where blowing the stack can cause a process to exit without a stack overflow exception.

Comment: @EricLippert hmm, that might be the case. How do i check that without the program exiting? And is there any way i can avoid that by modifying the above code? Also, a detail i forgot to mention in the question was that it worked properly the first time. Subsequent runs all failed.

Comment: I want to emphasize that this is a rare condition. What has to happen is, unmanaged code touches the last stack guard page, which triggers a stack exception, which Windows requires that you handle and reset the guard on the page. If you fail to do so before the *next* time you touch the guard page, then Windows takes down the process without throwing any exception; it just instantly terminates. I used to have to debug that condition all the time back in the 1990s; I used a kernel debugger. But I was building stack overflow detection into programming languages at the time.

Comment: I see. That is good info to know. It's a bummer that such basic code isn't working. I'll try changing the code a bit to see if it works or just use a concurrent queue to handle the parallel processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer by Nish26](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49434870/958732) is correct for the issue in the question.

I would propose solving your producer/consumer problem with [Microsoft TPL Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow/) instead:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

var parallelBoundedOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    BoundedCapacity = 100,
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2,
};
var uploadItemBlock = new ActionBlock<XElement>(
    item => ProcessItem(item),
    parallelBoundedOptions
);
string metadataFilePath = exportLocation + listTitle + "\\Metadata\\" + exportJobId + ".xml";
XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(metadataFilePath);
var query = from c in xmlFile.Elements("Items").Elements("Item")
            where c.Attribute("IsUploaded").Value == "No"
            select c;
foreach (var item in query)
{
    uploadItemBlock.SendAsync(item).Wait();
}
uploadItemBlock.Complete();
uploadItemBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

Dataflow makes it easier to focus on producing and consuming the items instead of how to pass them from the producer to the consumer.

The actual issue in the question is that [`Parallel.Foreach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747(v=vs.110).aspx) is using [`BlockingCollection<T>.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267242(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [`BlockingCollection<T>.GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186(v=vs.110).aspx) as demonstrated here:

```
static void Main()
{
    var collection = new BlockingCollection<int>(100);
    Task.Run(()=>
    {
        foreach (var element in Enumerable.Range(0, 100_000))
        {
            collection.Add(element);
        }
        collection.CompleteAdding();
    });

    Parallel.ForEach(
        collection, 
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2},
        i => Console.WriteLine(i));

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Prints "Done" immediately

```
static void Main()
{
    var collection = new BlockingCollection<int>(100);
    Task.Run(()=>
    {
        foreach (var element in Enumerable.Range(0, 100_000))
        {
            collection.Add(element);
        }
        collection.CompleteAdding();
    });

    Parallel.ForEach(
        collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(), 
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2},
        i => Console.WriteLine(i));

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Prints all the numbers

Comment: Good call. Will try it out as soon as I'm near my dev box.

Answer (score 2):

With the assumption that you are trying to run a console application, i can think of following issues :

1. Tasks in C# are by default **background threads** i.e. they can't keep the application alive. If the main thread exits which is a foreground thread, your background threads will stop executing as well.
2. With #1 in mind , it is possible that your parallel block is getting executed before there is any data generated by your producer thread and hence the *program exits leading to termination of the background producer thread* as well. Try to start consumer task where you read from collection using TryTake() inside a loop and add a call to Console.ReadLine() in your program to ensure console can't exit without user hitting enter. If you want to consume parallely, see example 2 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.1).

You can see some more examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.1).
Try to notice the following things in example code :

1. Use of using block  **using (BlockingCollection bc = new BlockingCollection())**
2. Calling method **CompleteAdding()** in the first thread which indicates that the collection won't accept any more item additions by the producer. This is called by the producer thread once all the items have been added.After a collection has been marked as complete for adding, adding to the collection is not permitted and attempts to remove from the collection will not wait when the collection is empty.
3. Use of **TryTake(out result)** by the consumer thread in second example.
   The consumer thread starts and tries to take out value.Even if the producer thread has not added any item , it will keep waiting since collection has not been marked for IsAddingCompleted by calling CompleteAdding() by producer thread. Consumer thread will get a false return value from TryTake when collection has been marked for IsAddingCompleted and collection is empty i.e. IsCompleted property of collection becomes true allowing consumer thread to finish.

4.Call to **Console.ReadLine()** so that both the Tasks which are background thread don't terminate without completing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Will try your suggestions out and see if it works. And yes, it is a console app.

Comment: Just to complete your answer, `Parallel.Foreach` calls [`BlockingCollection<T>.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267242(v=vs.110).aspx) which has the following remark: Unlike GetConsumingEnumerable, BlockingCollection<T>.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator returns a standard enumerator that does not modify the underlying collection. If other threads are adding or removing elements concurrently when GetEnumerator is called, then the elements returned by the enumerator might not represent the current state of the collection.

Comment: @Johnbot i had tried using Take() as well and while debugging, i noticed the collection changing but the program still used to exit. So i think it's not just related to `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: You could try just changing `Parallel.ForEach(collection,` to `Parallel.ForEach(collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(),`

Comment: Clearly explained  @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186(v=vs.110).aspx what @Johnbot has suggested.